# Can I export descriptive test names in Selenium / Gherkin / Cucumber?

Tags: visual-studio, selenium, automated-tests, gherkin

I have a few tests in feature files that use the Scenario Template method to plug in multiple parameters. For example:

```
@MaskSelection
Scenario Template: The Mask Guide Is Available
    Given the patient is using "<browser>"
    And A patient registered and logged in
    And A patient selected the mask
    When the patient clicks on the "<guide>"
    Then the patient should see the "<guide>" guide for the mask with "<guideLength>" slides
    Examples:
    | browser          | guide       | guideName                       | guideLength |
    | chrome           | mask        | Mask                   | 5           |
    | firefox          | replacement | Mask Replacement Guide | 6           |
    | internetexplorer | replacement | Mask Replacement Guide | 6           |
```

Currently, this is exporting test results with names like "TheMaskGuideIsAvailableVariant3". Is there any way to have it instead export something like "TheMaskGuideIsAvailable("chrome", "mask", "Mask", "5")"? I have a few tests which export 50+ results, and it's a pain to count the list to figure out exactly which set of parameters failed. I could have sworn the export used to work like this at one time, but I can't seem to replicate that behavior.

Possibly tied to it, recently, I've lost the ability to double-click on the test instance in Test Explorer in Visual Studio and go to the test outline in its file. Instead, nothing happens and I have to manually go to that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the Variant situation is that the part that gets appended is the first column of the table. If there are non-unique items in the first column, it gets exported as numbered "Variants".

The answer I found to exporting the list is to use vstest.console with the "/ListTests" option. As per the prior paragraph, since the first column is the one to be used for naming, a column can be established with a concatenated list of parameters.